# sudo fails to ask for password if libpam-tacplus is installed

Tags: sudo, password

With an updated Ubuntu 23.10 installation (as of 2024-01-25), running anything with sudo fails to ask for a password. It just hangs forever. Running strace, I noticed that it was blocking on a read() from the fd pointing to the tty, so on a hunch I just entered the password without the prompt, and then the command runs as expected.

Has anyone seen this behaviour?

sudo is at version 1.9.14p2-1ubuntu1, and permissions on /dev/tty look normal:

```
$ ls -l /dev/tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 2024-01-25 15:17 /dev/tty
$ groups
peter adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd
```

(I've rebooted a couple of times, just to make sure the system wasn't in a weird state).

If I press Enter once I do get a password prompt:

```
$ sudo ls
<press Enter>
[sudo] password for peter: 
^Csudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

UPDATE: I had installed the libpam-tacplus package (there is a very old version in Ubuntu, which I am working replacing with a modern version as the product I am developing at $DAYJOB requires it). Removing this package restores the prompt.

Comment: It seems the first printed line `[sudo] password for peter:` doesn't show in your terminal and thus when you press Enter it is counted as `1` failed attempt and then the next line is visible ... Look into modifications/customization related to that ... probably in your terminal's settings or even in the automatically sourced files by your shell like `~/.bashrc` and probably done by you long time ago but was tolerated by older versions of related packages.

Comment: Have you examined `/var/log/auth.log`? Have you made any changes to PAM? Does your system use any non-standard authentication methods, such as fprintd or LDAP?

Comment: @steeldriver: Thanks, each sudo log is paired with a log about PAM-tacplus being unconfigured, which led me in the right direction.

Comment: @nafmo it would be great if you could find time to write up an answer briefly explaining how you diagnosed + fixed the issue

Comment: @steeldriver I noticed references to the libpam-tacplus plugin in the auth.log you mentioned, so I tried uninstalling the library, and then the regular prompting reappeared. I have now upgrade to a more recent version, as the version in Debian/Ubuntu is quite old (and I haven't had my GnuPG key in the Debian keyring for 15+ years, so I can't fix it).